# Slow test suite with Ruby 1.9.2 and Rspec 2.5

Tags: rspec

I've started a Rails 3 project using Ruby 1.9.2 and Rspec 2 and my
test suite is now growing and I'm not happy with the amount of time it
is tooking to run. I did a benchmark of it with Ruby Enterprise
Edition 1.8.7 2011.03 and it ran much more faster(5x) than Ruby 1.9.2.

Is it expected or there is something I'm missing? To see the results,
Gemfile and spec_helper.rb please check the gist
https://gist.github.com/939699

Any help or tips are very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rspec runs its own specs faster on 1.9.2 than on 1.8.7: 
https://gist.github.com/939865

Which version of rails are you using, and what other gems are in your 
Gemfile?

Answer (score 1):

You may want to try something like Spork to keep from having to load the application each time it needs to run the tests.  I have found the time savings using it to be pretty significant.

The following link is a railscast with a pretty good  introduction to Spork:
 http://railscasts.com/episodes/285-spork